# CORS Issue NestJS and Vercel only when doing POST requests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nestjs, vercel

GET requests work fine  but I am using SWR to do POST requests to submit things to firebase and mutate things in state like this but i can not do post requests

```
const item = await fetcher.POST(`/jobs?user_id=${user.id}`, _job)

        mutate(item)
```

fetcher is setup like this HOST being the route to the api

```
fetcher.POST = (
  url,
  data,
  headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
) => {
  return fetcher(HOST + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
}
```

This is my error in console ----
Access to fetch at 'https://example-api.vercel.app/v1/jobs?user_id=8JKY8PRM5APwIz1' from origin 'https://workshop-4i8ymvm1s.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

On my NestJS serverless function i have setup cors like this in my index.ts & main.ts file. (Is this an issue?) ---

```
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    snapshot: true,
    logger: new Logg(),
    cors: true
  });
```

&&

```
  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: '*',
    origin: '*',
    credentials: false,
  });
```

I've gone through the docs but can't seem to see alternatives.

i have tried on postman and it works but that isn't using a browser but was to test if it works and it does.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a **vercel.json** file in your nestjs api?

Vercel will override your cors configuration, so create a file at the root of your nest project like the code below. Please change the paths to match with your code structure and **make sure you have the OPTIONS method, because that's needed for POST requests.**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "src/main.ts",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "DELETE",
        "PATCH",
        "OPTIONS"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```